# Best way to load frames of video with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, tf.data.dataset

I was working on a video classification problem. the data is given as frames per video so I created a generator that takes an array of videos with dim = (batch_size, #frames, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3) with `keras.utils.Sequence`

I was working on Kaggle notebooks and the code was working fine then I used the same code in a python script to run it on my machine and I found that the code was not using the GPU

I did some research and some people suggested that to use `tf.data` instead of `keras.utils.Sequence` but I didn't find a way to do that

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
import math

class imgs_gen(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size, IMG_SIZE):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.img_size = IMG_SIZE

    def __len__(self):        
        return int(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)


    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        
        vedios_batch = self.x[idx * self.batch_size : (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = [int(x[3:]) - 1 for x in  self.y[idx * self.batch_size : (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]]
        
       
        X = np.array([[resize(imread(file_name), (self.img_size, self.img_size)) for file_name in imgs_batch] for imgs_batch in vedios_batch])
        y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(batch_y , num_classes=16)
        
       
        return X, y
```

Comment: Your try another script and see that is effectively use the GPU ?

Comment: I tried another script that was working on the same problem but classifying each frame individually. I loaded the frames with Keras ImageDataGenerator and it was working fine

Comment: That's odd maybe keras sequence don't use the tf distribute strategy try to use `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` with your keras sequence to see if that works